# How to better update pivot table data filter?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm using this code below to update pivot table filter.
It only filters items under date field equal to todays date.
It is workning fine but is there a faster way to do this?

```
Dim wsPivot1 as Worksheet
Dim pt as PivotTable
Dim pt_item as PivotItem

Set wsPivot1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Pivot")

For Each pt In wsPivot1.PivotTables
    pt.RefreshTable
    If DatePart("h", Now()) < 6 Then
        date_stamp = Format(Now() - 1, "m/d/yyyy")
    Else
        date_stamp = Format(Now(), "m/d/yyyy")
    End If
    If pt.Name = "PivotTable1" Then
        pt.PivotFields("Date_Adj").ClearAllFilters
        For Each pt_item In pt.PivotFields("Date_Adj").PivotItems
            Select Case pt_item.Name
            Case date_stamp
                pt_item.Visible = True
            Case Else
                pt_item.Visible = False
            End Select
        Next pt_item
    End If
Next pt
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems like you only want to show one date and hide the rest, you can create a custom filter for that date. Replace your `for` loop, i.e.

```
For Each pt_item In pt.PivotFields("Date_Adj").PivotItems
    Select Case pt_item.Name
        Case date_stamp
            pt_item.Visible = True
        Case Else
            pt_item.Visible = False
    End Select
Next pt_item
```

With this line

```
pt.PivotFields("Date_Adj").PivotFilters.Add _
    Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=date_stamp
```

Note that the above code will only work if the values in your "Date_Adj" column are stored as dates. If they are not, you'll need to use this line of code instead

```
pt.PivotFields("Date_Adj").PivotFilters.Add _
    Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=date_stamp
```

**EXAMPLE**
Understanding that my sample data may be severly oversimplified, this is what I used to test my solution (Note: Sample created using Excel 2007).

[image: Sample Data]

"Ship Date" is an entered date; "Date_Adj" is just the left adjacent cell + 1 (e.g. `=B2+1`).

Then I created the Pivot table and ran the code as you'll see in the image below

[image: Pivot Table and Macro]

Comment: Thanks for the code but this doesn't seem to work. i get a `object defined` error.

Comment: try replacing `Value1:=date_stamp` with `Value1:=DateValue(date_stamp)` and let me know if that works. If so I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: hi Jaycal, it does not work either. But I've already figured out why. it doesn't work because that `Method` is not supported by `PivotTable` object. You can only use that `Method` on `Range` objects which should contain your filter. See my answer for the working code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the method suggested by Jaycal.
Suppose you have a Pivot table in "Pivot" Sheet with filter in Range("A2").

This code works:

```
Dim wsPivot1 as Worksheet
Dim cel as Range


Set wsPivot1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Pivot")
Set cel = wsPivot1.Range("A2")

cel.PivotField.PivotFilters.Add xlCaptionEquals, "Date_Adj", date_stamp
```

It has one limitation though.
It will work on filters in Row and Column labels only.
Not on Report Filters.

**Edit1:** Use this if your working on `Report Filters`.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each pt in wsPivot1
    pt.RefreshTable
    pt.PivotFields("Date_Adj").ClearAllFilters
    pt.PivotFields("Date_Adj").CurrentPage = date_stamp
Next
```

Comment: Interesting. I tested the answer I posted for you in both 2007 & 2010 and it worked fine. Probably because the your data is setup up differently than the simple sample data I put together. Glad you were able to get it to work :)

Comment: yeah i was interested in your approach and take time reading more about it and thus arrived on the above code. but, could you somehow post how your pivot table is organized and how you're able to use it in `Pivottable` object? it will improve coding tremendously avoiding the `PivotItem` looping.

Comment: Updated my answer with some sample data and code. Take a look and let me know what you think

Comment: ah got it. now i see it works as well as long as the filter is on either `Row Labels` or `Column Labels` area. but try putting `Date_Adj` in the `Report Filter` area, it is not possible.